# Identifying a reduced relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses

I came across this sentence today but am not sure if this is a reduced relative clause.

> These six categories are also consistent with those used to group the multiple-choice questions included in this chapter.

Can **that/which are** be understood to be in the sentence?

> These six categories are also consistent with those **that/which are** used to group the multiple-choice questions included in this chapter.

If the above sentence is correct,and since that/which represents **those**
 can the relative clause be viewed as:

Those are used to group the multiple-choice questions included in this chapter.

Answer (score 2):

Almost!

You've correctly identified that the first sentence contains a reduced relative clause.  Fantastic!

However you've got the corresponding relative clause in your second sentence just slightly wrong.  The correct relative clause is:

> which are used to group the multiple-choice questions included in this
> chapter

The word "which" here functions as the clausal subject.  Notice that the relative clause cannot stand on its own as a sentence!  The clause that you wrote down:

> those are used to group the multiple-choice questions included in this
> chapter

*could* stand on its own as a sentence:

> These six categories are also consistent with those. Those are used to group the multiple-choice questions included in this chapter.

...and so it is an independent clause, not a relative clause.  Because of this. you would need to connect it with "and" if you were using it in the same sentence.

By the way - the two example sentences in your question are both correct and interchangeable - although most styles guides would argue you should always prefer fewer words when possible - and thus use the first.

Answer (score 0):

> These six categories are also consistent with those **that / which are** used to group the multiple-choice questions included in this chapter.

is correct.

---

> Those are used to group the multiple-choice questions included in this chapter.

Extracted from the context, it is still correct with a similar meaning.

Comment: May I ask why you didn’t put any article before “similar meaning”?

Comment: Yes, you may :) I work for 2 years in an environment where colleagues have difficulties communicating in English (and that is the only common language). To facilitate communication, I "simplify" my English - for the sake of communication. I am aware that I make more and more mistakes because of this, but with all attention paid, some (mistakes) get into the wild. Thank you for noticing.

Comment: I don't think the grammar that omits the 'a' is some kind of shorthand or shortcut.  It's perfectly valid.  Compare "The second cake has similar flavor" vs. "The second cake has a similar flavor".  This has to do with the noun being count / non-count, or in this case either.   It wouldn't work at all with a strictly counted noun:  "The second chair has smaller leg" is totally wrong, but a non-counted noun is OK:  "The second chair has prettier fabric".

Comment: @BadZen: Your explanation actually makes sense. Thanks. I have never thought of it that way.